# Moving of floating objects

Tags: floats

In my latex document I used :

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ID_decays.png}
\caption{Differet parameters of Inner Detector \cite{12}.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

then why my objects are always moves to another place?

Comment: Check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text... But check both answers... Also, if it solves your problem tell as to mark your question as a dupplicate.

Comment: Most often asked LaTeX question ever. It got already answered several times.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?s=1|0.0000#39020  But basically, that is because floats are SUPPOSED to move.  I have yet to find a case where `!` makes a useful difference.